# How to replace key string in dictionary with Python and regex?

Tags: python, regex

How to replace a key string extracting data from it using regex with Python, example :

```
{"root['toto']": {'new_value': 'abcdef', 'old_value': 'ghijk'}}
```

I'd like to replace `root['toto']` with something easier to read, like `toto` and my object might have several key like this, that I'd like to extract inside `root['']`.

Comment: This is not JSON, it's a dictionary. I'm removing the tag.

Comment: copy to a new dict

Comment: `{ k[6:-2] if k[:6]=="root['" else k :v for k,v in d.items() }` where `d` is your old dictionary

Comment: @bulbus It's a bit complicated to read, but should work

Comment: posted as an answer to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following regular expression:

```
mydict = {
    "root['toto']": {'new_value': 'abcdef', 'old_value': 'ghijk'},
    "test['aaa']": {'new_value': 'abcdef', 'old_value': 'ghijk'},
    "root['bb']": {'new_value': 'abcdef', 'old_value': 'ghijk'},
    "ccc": {'new_value': 'abcdef', 'old_value': 'ghijk'}
    }

for key, value in mydict.items():
    new_key = re.sub(r"(\w+\[')(\w+)('\])", r"\2", key)

    if new_key != key:
        mydict[new_key] = mydict.pop(key)  # Remove the old entry and add the entry back with new key

print mydict
```

Giving you an updated `mydict` containing:

```
{'aaa': {'new_value': 'abcdef', 'old_value': 'ghijk'}, 
'bb': {'new_value': 'abcdef', 'old_value': 'ghijk'}, 
'toto': {'new_value': 'abcdef', 'old_value': 'ghijk'}, 
'ccc': {'new_value': 'abcdef', 'old_value': 'ghijk'}}
```

Comment: This was exactly the solution I was looking for ;)

Answer (score 1):

If your key all have type 'root[*]', you can use :

```
newkey = oldkey.replace("['"," ").replace("']","").split()[1]
```

Comment: Or just `oldkey.replace("root['", '').replace("']", '')`

Comment: @Phước Hữu Lưu That works great, simple, efficient, I like this kind of comment ;)

Comment: @Rawing it's also necessary to `replace("']","")`

Answer (score 1):

```
d={ k[6:-2] if k[:6]=="root['" else k :v for k,v in d.items() }
```

where d is your dictionary object

**example**

```
d={"root['abc']":2,'3':4}
d={ k[6:-2] if k[:6]=="root['" else k :v for k,v in d.items() }
print(d)
```

**output**

```
{'abc': 2, '3': 4}
```

**explanation**

we use dictionary comprehension to create a new dictionary.

breaking down the line:-

```
{                                    #Start dictionary construction 
k[6:-2] if k[:6]=="root['" else k    # this is our new key
:                                    # key value separator
v                                    #Keep the same value as the old one.
for k,v in d.items()                 #Do this for all key,values in my old dictionary.
}                                    #End dictionary construction
```

---

**without using dict comprehension**

```
d={"root['abc']":2,'3':4}                 #d is our old dict
nd={}                                     #nd is new dict
for k,v in d.items():                     #iterating over each key,value k,v
  nk= k[6:-2] if k[:6]=="root['" else k   #nk is our new key
  nd[nk]=v                                #setting nk:v in nd
print(nd)                                 #print final dict
```

**output**

```
{'abc': 2, '3': 4}
```